# Youtube API loadVideoById can't disable autoplay ( tested on iOS devices)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Note! the problem occured on iOS devices like the iPad

How can I load youtube videos using the Youtube Player API and disable autoplay?
and also be able to stop the video

Problems:

- loadVideoById the video starts rights away.
- cueVideoById the video load but does not show the thumbnail

Example code;
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13780885/loadvideobyid/autoplay.html

Youtube Player API documentation:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054930/disable-autoplay-in-youtube-javascript-api